# When unplugging one monitor from dual monitor setup, apps/programs don't switch to other monitor automatically

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I am using Windows 10 and did not have this problem until about 3 days ago

I have a dual monitor setup

My left monitor is my main monitor and my right monitor is my secondary monitor

I will often unplug my main monitor and plug in my PS4 to play games

Before this problem started occurring, I would unplug my main monitor and all browser windows, apps and programs would automatically switch/jump to the monitor on the right

I don't know if I unknowingly altered some settings but now when I unplug the main monitor, all apps/browser windows etc will be in limbo and I will have to move them one by one using the windows button + right arrow key to my secondary monitor

I have made no hardware changes - the only thing I can think of is that there was a Windows 10 update - but would seem odd that it would affect my dual monitor setup

Has anyone encountered this problem?  Would appreciate a solution

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to
Windows (Start Button) > Settings (Gear Icon) > System > Scroll Down to Multitasking

and make sure everything is set for a second display (the two virtual desktop settings at the bottom).

Enter Windows Key and P key and the “Project” menu will appear. There are four types of display methods that can be chosen. If you want to expand the desktop UI over two screens, select the “Extend” option.
PC screen only: used only to view the original display unit – the additional unit will be blank
Duplicate: used to display the same image on both displays
Extend: used to extend the desktop UI across the two displays; making your computer screen ‘longer.’
Second screen only: used only to display the additional display unit – the original will become blank

Comment: thanks but your suggestions didn't work - I didn't touch any of the settings you mentioned - every thing was working fine...then a couple of days ago all my open programs wouldn't jump to the secondary monitor after unplugging my main one